# Every stable homotopical functor factors through $\mathbf{SH}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, motivic-cohomology, motivic-homotopy, six-operations

In this [nlab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motivic+homotopy+theory), it says that the fact that every stable homotopical functor factors through $\mathbf{SH}$ (the motivic stable homotopy category of Morel-Voevodsky) is proven in Ayoub's thesis. Howeve, as far as I can say, in Ayoub's theis: the first and second chapters deal with the construction of six operations, the third chapter is about nearby cycles functors, the last one is about the construction of $\mathbf{SH}$ but just the construction, there is no such a result.

Can somebody give me a reference for this result? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The nLab claim is only true if you take into account the monoidal structure and consider functors valued in ∞-categories. A reference is the paper by Drew and Gallauer, "The universal six-functor formalism".

Comment: @MarcHoyois, is it still true if $2$-functors take values in model categories?

Comment: This will certainly depend on the model category you choose for SH; maybe there is one with a suitable universal property. In any case, Drew-Gallauer is the only reference.